# Process builder add a specific amount of weeks or months to a date

Tags: formula, process-builder

I have a picklist field on Opportunity called `Delivery_Followup__c` with the values: 2 Weeks, 3 Weeks, 1 Month.

I have a process builder that creates a task to followup with the customer and we want to set the due date to be Today() + `Delivery_Followup__c`.

Is there a way to add the weeks/month to the Today() function in a process builder formula?

Answer (score 1):

Use the CASE function.

TODAY() + 
CASE ( Delivery_Followup__c, 
       "2 Weeks", 14 , 
       "3 Weeks", 21 ,
       "1 Month", 30 , 
       0
      )

Comment: Although 1 month can be anywhere from 28 to 31 days...

Comment: @AdrianLarson this is acceptable for the most cases, otherwise he would have to deal with a complex formula like search for 'Adding Days, Months, and Years to a Date' [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_examples_dates.htm)